# Using pyparsing to match against a specific ending of a string

Tags: python, pyparsing

How can I build a python pyparsing structure that matches against a particular string ending. For example, suppose I want to find all words that end in 'ing'. The following does NOT work:

`ing_ending = Word(alphas) + Literal("ing") + White();`
`ing_ending.parseString("jumping")`

This would be pretty easy to do in python and regex but gives me trouble in pyparsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use regex

```
>>> import pyparsing
>>> ing_ending = pyparsing.Regex(r'(?i)\b[a-z]+ing\b')
>>> ing_ending.parseString("jumping")
(['jumping'], {})
```